# how to number lines of txt file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerated-types

I want to analyze a specific part of a txt.file (lines 48-392) and I have problems numbering the single lines of the txt file.
This is what I was able to come up so far:

```
with open ('kafka_hungerkuenstler.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
    #I tried: enumerate (line)
    #there should also be something like read_selected_lines (filename, 48,392) somewhere in
     the code      
        print (line)
```

Comment: Is that the 49th line (counting from 0) or the 48th line (counting from 1)?

Comment: it's the 48th line counting from 1

Comment: replace `for line in f:` with `for line in f.readlines()[47:392]:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to pick a certain range of lines:

```
from itertools import islice

with open ('kafka_hungerkuenstler.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in islice(f, 47, 392):
```

The loop will only iterate over lines 47 (counting from zero) until 391, inclusive; counting from 1 that's line 48 through to 392, inclusive.